# android studio emulator hangs on startup on m1

Tags: android-emulator, apple-m1

I'm trying to run Android Studio emulator version 31.3.13.0 on MacOS 12.5.1 with M1. The emulator hangs with no error message after the following lines:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator$ ./emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_33 -verbose -show-kernel
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.13.0 (build_id 9189900) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'Pixel_5_API_33'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: arm64
INFO    | argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: /Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
INFO    | emuDirName: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
INFO    | try dir /Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
VERBOSE | Adding library search path for Qt: '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
VERBOSE | Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
VERBOSE | Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
VERBOSE | Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
VERBOSE | Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
VERBOSE | Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
VERBOSE | emulator: Running :/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[00] = "/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_5_API_33"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[04] = "-show-kernel"
VERBOSE | Concatenated backend parameters:  /Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64 -avd Pixel_5_API_33 -verbose -show-kernel
```

Any help would be appreciated.